# Cannot get the same address format from zeroMQ and Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core, address, zeromq

I use nodejs with this npm library:

```
const bitcoinjs = require('bitcoinjs-lib');  // version "^5.1.6"
```

I received a rawTx from zeroMq, then extract it:

```
const tx = bitcoinjs.Transaction.fromHex(rawTx);
```

the txID is 8dba72608cbfca197b55d86aae2817d11f829b9361eb421fb005616f48ce8401

if I take the first output:

```
let output = tx.outs[0];
```

then I try to get the address:

```
const scriptBuffer = Buffer.from(output.script);
const address = bitcoinjs.address.fromOutputScript(scriptBuffer);
```

I get:

> 37XE9EYzix7S42fLMxutrNaPfDbCccLhiT

But from bitcoin core I get:

> 2My5SCyV2LQcnFpHt36XmUKZesZoNRQRPa5

My question: how do I convert the address to the same format as bitcoin core ?

Comment: You need to tell bitcoinjs to use the testnet settings

Comment: @Raghav Sood You should turn that into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Raghav Sood: you are right: here the correct code:

```
const addresses = bitcoinjs.address.fromOutputScript(outputScript, bitcoinjs.networks.testnet);
```

Thanks :-)